# How to put character dynamically in a drawable?

Tags: android

In my android project I have created a circle shape in the drawable folder. Now I want to put a character inside that shape dynamically to create a icon. How can I do this? please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a TextView and set its background to that circle shape

Sample Shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#c20586">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#fa09ad"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

xml

```
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

or set text from activity

```
TextView headerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
headerValue.setText(jsonValue );
```

Comment: But I want to put a character that i am getting from a JSON dynamically.

Comment: I have updated the answer you can set text dynamically